# codeigniter4 redirect not working outside index function

Tags: php, redirect, codeigniter-4

I tried various type of redirect function but none of them are working. I am simply creating one function where I testing the session availability and based on that redirect will work. But when session_check function is getting called only text part Iam getting and redirect is not working. I tried to, route, site_url but nothing works.

```
<?php

namespace App\Controllers;
use CodeIgniter\HTTP\CLIRequest;
use CodeIgniter\HTTP\IncomingRequest;
use CodeIgniter\HTTP\RequestInterface;
use CodeIgniter\HTTP\ResponseInterface;
use App\Controllers\BaseController;

class Home extends BaseController
{
    public function session_check()
    {
        $session = session();
        if ($session->has('usernamesession'))
        { 
            echo 'yes';
            return redirect()->to('public/home');
        }
        else
        {
            echo 'NoA';
            return redirect()->to('/public/login111'); 
            //return redirect()->to(site_url("list-user"));
            //return redirect()->route("login");
            //return redirect()->back();
            //return $routes->addRedirect('home', 'login');
            echo 'NoB';
        }
    }

public function index()
{
    echo 'Home';
    $this->session_check();
}
```

}

Comment: https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/common_functions.html#redirect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I tried the below mentioned code and it's working for me, any further improvement is highly appreciated.

Controller **Home** Function:

```
<?php

namespace App\Controllers;
use App\Libraries\Cv;
use CodeIgniter\HTTP\CLIRequest;
use CodeIgniter\HTTP\IncomingRequest;
use CodeIgniter\HTTP\RequestInterface;
use CodeIgniter\HTTP\ResponseInterface;
use App\Controllers\BaseController;

class Home extends BaseController
{
    public function index()
    {
        $this->session_check();
        $data['top_header']=view('theme/top_header');
        $data['sidebar_menu']=view('theme/sidebar_menu');
        $data['body_content']=view('theme/body_content');
        $data['tab']=view('theme/tab');
        $data['footer']=view('theme/footer');
        return view('theme/index',$data);
    }
}
?>
```

**BaseController.php**

```
public function session_check()
{
    $this->session->set("usernamesession",'Naresh');
    
    if (!$this->session->has('usernamesession'))
    { 
        return $this->response->redirect(site_url('public/login'));
    }else{}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
public function session_check()
{
    $session = session();
    if ($session->has('usernamesession'))
    { 
        return 'public/home';
    }
    else
    {
        return '/public/login111'; 
    }
}

public function index()
{
    echo 'Home';
    $url = $this->session_check();

    return redirect()->to($url);
}
```

Codeigniter is not as friendly in v4 as it was in v3 when it comes to redirecting. I highly suspect this will resolve your issue.

Comment: This is not working, it's going for an infinite loop.